# gapi this.fl is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-api-js-client

I'm attempting to load Google API in a simple React app, but I keep getting this annoying error - see below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.fl is not a function
  at _.C.ria (cb=gapi.loaded_0:82)
  at _.C.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:596)
  at h.r2 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:82)
  at xs (cb=gapi.loaded_0:85)
  at Wq (cb=gapi.loaded_0:85)
  at _.C.uea (cb=gapi.loaded_0:85)
  at Ap (cb=gapi.loaded_0:78)
  at <anonymous>
```

Even if I try to include some console log statements in my code, I see them briefly on execution, and then they are cleared and replaced by this error message.

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import './App.css'
import AppHeader from '../AppHeader'


var GoogleAuth


class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => this.setState({user}))

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'

    script.onload = () => {
      if (!GoogleAuth) {
        window.gapi.load('client', () => {
          window.gapi.client.init({
            clientId: 'XXXX',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
          })
          .then(() => GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance())
        })
      }
    }

    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppHeader user={this.state.user} />
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: i'm having the same problem in a vue project. did you figured out what the problem was @artooras ?

Comment: To be fair, I'm not sure what the issue was, but I'm not experiencing it anymore (for now!). The changes I have made are quite trivial, like loading 'client:auth2' now and checking `if (user !== this.state.user)` before `setState` in `onAuthStateChanged`, but I doubt these were the cause...

Comment: Got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Init returns an instance of GoogleAuth. So instead of trying to getAuthInstance() off of the window like you're doing here

```
window.gapi.client.init({
  clientId: 'XXXX',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
})
.then(() => GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance())
```

I had to use the return from init

```
window.gapi.client.init({
  clientId: 'XXXX',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
})
.then(GoogleAuth => {
   // no need to call getAuthInstance, you have it as the resolution of the init promise
   // GoogleAuth.signIn();
   // GoogleAuth.signOut();
   // etc.
});
```